# Docker Compose yml file - Environment variables

Tags: json, docker, docker-compose, yaml

https://github.com/sipcapture/homer7-docker/tree/master/heplify-server/hom7-prom-all

I'm using a docker compose from the above link.

I know how to set environment variables but i would like to know how to get a list of the variables i can use?

I've tried to google for it but its seems the algorithm favors results how to set them and not how to know what variables you can set for each docker you compose so maybe its not possible or im just lacking in my google skills. Sorry in advance if the latter is true.

Comment: You want a list of defined environment variables? That depends on the system? For linux systems the [`printenv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/printenv.1.html) command should do that.  And if you are using a `.env` file, well, then the file contains the defined variables ...

Comment: so use this command on the docker shell and it will show all the environment variables i can set?

Comment: No. You cannot get a list of environment variables you can use, other than by reading the documentation for the specific image with which you're working.

Comment: Ah, you want to find out what variables can/must be set for a specific image? You can only get this information from the docs of that image ...

Comment: You can set any string you want as an environment variable, but it may or may not have an effect.  Neither Docker nor Unix in general defines any sort of vocabulary or schema around environment variables.